# Most natural way to express "It's later now."

Tags: grammar, phrases

I've been keeping a journal in Japanese, and recently I wrote a paragraph about something I was planning to do, and then after I had done it, I wrote another paragraph about how it went. I wanted to write something along the lines of "It's later now." at the start of the second paragraph, to indicate that there was a break in time between the first and second paragraph. I came up with two possibilities, but I'm not sure if either sounds correct, much less natural:

- 後{あと}だ。
- 今{いま}の方{ほう}が遅{おそ}い。

What is the most natural way to express this?

Comment: I think I understand your question by and large, but I'm not sure how you want to use the phrase "it's later now". Does it need to be an independent sentence? What the next sentence goes like?

Comment: I'm thinking for a scenario like: "... so I'm thinking about going to the store later today. <paragraph break> It's later now. I went to the store about an hour ago, and ..." It feels very strange to juxtapose those two sentences without somehow acknowledging that time has passed between when they were written.

Comment: Oh... in that case, I think I'd put 「続き。」 or 「追記。」 in its place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I doubt 後だ or 今の方が遅い will work. And I cannot think of a short phrase that looks similar and can be used in this context. Instead, you can:

1. Just place a enough space or a horizontal line, and explain time has passed. (e.g. "前の文を書いてから5時間経った。", "そんなわけで実際に行ってきた。", "今これを書いているのはお店から帰ってきた後だ。") Here そんなわけで is used as an introductory conjunction similar to "So, ...".
2. Use 追記, 追加, 続き, optionally with the actual time (e.g, "21:05 追記")